# Компьютер не загружается с DVD-RW-диска

Tags: железо, диск

Я стал обладателем старой вычислительной машины 2000-х годов, и так произошло, что он перестал грузить гибкий диск и грузит вместо него винчестер. Кроме того, даже если в вариантах загрузки в BIOS выбрать только гибкий диск и ничего больше, компьютер всё равно загрузит жесткий диск. Причём гибкий диск исправен и читается. Может ли быть, что загрузчик GRUB на жестком диске забирает загрузку? Как решить эту проблему?

```
Boot from CD/DVD
Grub loading...
Welcome to GRUB!
```

Comment: А у вас граб на жёстком диске, а на "дискете" нету? Вы дискетой называете DVD-Диск, или таки дискету? Почему у вас в вопросе DVD а потом плавный переход на дискету?

Comment: @nick_n_a мой словарный запас небольшой, мне всего 13 лет, а так у меня DVD с Windows XP

Comment: DVD-диск является загрузочным? Вероятнее всего нет. Поэтому после неудачной попытки загрузки с него продолжается загрузка с HDD.

Comment: Загрузочный DVD-диск - его создание или копирование в разы сложнее чем дискеты или винчейстера. Есть несколько зависимостей и если хоть одно из условий не выполняется - то с такого диска нельзя загрузиться: 1 CD/DVD диск должен содержать загрузочную партицию (часть диска отдана на загрузку) 2. Партиция должна сожержать загрузчик, он не должен быть повреждён. 3.  Партиция должна сожержать загрузочные файлы, они не должны быть повреждены. 4. Желательно, что бы был совместимый с вашим оборудыванием драйвер DVD-дисковода, без него инфу с второй партиции прочесть не получится.

Comment: Если просто тупо скопировать файлы на диск - он загрузочным не будет. И если неправильно снят образ - то тоже ничего не выйдет. Надо найти хороший диск или образ, или научится делать загрузочный DVD самому.

Comment: Для установки винды - найдите установочный диск, как правило при загрузке с такого диска появляется табличка "Press key " и надо нажать клавишу для загрузки с DVD.

Comment: @nick_n_a я знаю, что и как делать, я записал диск с образа ISO и засунул его в дисковод, и ничего, и еще раз, но так ничего и не добился. Может, проблема в дисководе или в блоке питания, который недавно был заменен?

Comment: Вариант 1 - неправильный образ. Вариант 2 - привод не читает диск ( тогда он его секунд 30 мучает при старте, а потом идет грузится с винта).

Comment: Образ не битый, ставил с него раз десять на разных устройствах, но именно после замены бьющего током блока питания привод отвалился, причем какие бы кабели питания для привода я не подключал, постоянно происходит переброс загрузки

Comment: Если дисковод не исправен - загрузки не будет. Если биос дисковод не видит - загрузки с диска не будет. Если дисковод сгорел - сам не оживёт даже если замена БД была. БП бьют током в 99% случаев все, не бить током может только заземлённый с хорошим заземлением - в домашних условиях такое бывает очень редко.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я зашел в CMOS и на IDE канале 1 SLAVE был CD-привод. А DVD нет.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос в принципе не имеет смысла, так как я просто забыл поменять джампер на Master.

Comment: Правильный ответ - это инструкции по загрузке ПК, их можно накопать в сети, очень много тонкостей, от настроек биос (порядок загрузки, в разных биосах чуть по разному) до перемычек master-slave которые сегодня не используются. Если вопрос лишний - его можно удалить (есть пункт удалить). Если вопрос хороший - можно оставить, ответ тут принято давать более развёрнутый.